# sinonjs stup multiple ajax request

Tags: javascript, ajax, promise, sinon, testcase

I am new in to write the test case using sinonjs

I have the scenario, two ajax request using to display the value.
Example:
I just write the sample code format not actual code here.

Javascript Code:

```
function A(){
   test.ajaxPromise(url)
   .then(function(res) {
     B(res);
   }).catch(function() {
    showErrorMsg('Please enter a valid postcode');
  });
}

function B(res){
    test.ajaxPromise(url)
   .then(function(res) {
     document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = res.code;
   }).catch(function() {
    showErrorMsg('Please enter a valid postcode');
  });
}
```

I trying to write the integration test case, I am using phantomjs also. but I have two ajax promise function having, both function are returns different value. If I had one ajaxpromise functions means it's working fine.

Testcase code:

```
var stupAjaxPromise = function(data) {
    sinon.stub(test, 'ajaxPromise', function() {
        return {
            then: function(cb) {
                cb({
                    response: data
                });
                return {
                    catch: function() {
                    }
                };
            }
        };
    });
};

beforeEach(function() {
    var placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    placeholder.id = 'test';
    placeholder = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(placeholder);
    stupAjaxPromise(sampleData);
});

it ('Check Value', function(){
    var container = document.getElementById('test');    
    assert.equal('£50', container.innerText, 'Value not match');
});
```

Can anyone please help to resolve this. or give some Idea to solve it.

Comment: Which library or framework are you using for ajax?

Comment: I using var Promise = require('promise-polyfill');

Comment: You can push all the promises in an array and can use `Promise.all()` to resolve the promises